# @font-face not loading on Android 5.0.2 mobile phone despite loading on PC desktop

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-face

Problem:  @font-face font called 'Ubuntu-L' is not loading on my [HTC One](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2033315/review-htc-one-is-the-android-phone-to-beat.html) Android 5.0.2  despite loading on PC desktop, here is my page: [piotrdeja.pl](http://piotrdeja.pl/) you can check it on your mobile phone to see what I mean.

My page works as a wordpress theme, here is my functions.php excerpt although @font-face is directly declared in style.css. Functions.php:

```
    <?php 

        function learningWordpress_resources() {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'owl.carousel.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.carousel.min.css',false,'1.1','all');
            wp_enqueue_style( 'owl.theme.default.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.theme.default.min.css',false,'1.1','all');
            wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css',false,'1.1','all');
            wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-3.1.1', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.1.1.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap.min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'owl.carousel.min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

            wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'learningWordPress_resources');


    ?>
```

style.css :

```
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Ubuntu-L';
      src: url('fonts/Ubuntu-L.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
      src: url('fonts/Ubuntu-L.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
           url('fonts/Ubuntu-L.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
           url('fonts/Ubuntu-L.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
           url('fonts/Ubuntu-L.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
           url('fonts/Ubuntu-L.svg#svgUbuntu-L') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on your css code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) and (min-width: 1001px)
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Ubuntu-L;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: .8em;
    color: white;
}
```

You assigned the font with media query, you might want to change your code to something like this to apply the font in all screen sizes:

```
h2 {
   font-family: Ubuntu-L;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) and (min-width: 1001px)
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: .8em;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: The thing is that on PC desktop if I shrink the page to the mobile phone size - the font DOES load, but on actual mobile phone this font is not loading. Maby it is Android issue.